# What would be the correct formatting or rewording of the onomatopoeia "crunch-crunched"?

Tags: verbs, hyphenation, onomatopoeia, editing

I am editing a historical fiction novel, and this clause has come up.

> As the Model T's wheels crunch-crunched their way up the gravel driveway...

Is this clause grammatically correct? Should I use one of the following examples instead?:

the Model T's wheels crunch crunched

the Model T's wheels *crunch-crunched*

the Model T's wheels *crunch crunched*

the Model T's wheels crunched

the Model T's wheels went *crunch crunch*

Comment: If you italicize a sound effect, are you promising to italicize all future sound effects in the novel? Remember that you're training your readers as much as anything.

Comment: compare [clop-clopped](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clop-clopped), 
  [clip-clopped](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS724US727&biw=1093&bih=500&sxsrf=ALeKk00knP_LtlVUPzguAudKiJv2pgHHKA%3A1598659777676&ei=wZxJX_vZKMb8tAWO3ImgCg&q=%22clip+clopped%22&oq=%22clip+clopped%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQDDIHCAAQRhD5ATIECAAQHjIECAAQHjIECAAQHjIGCAAQChAeMgYIABAKEB5QlskEWIrOBGCN6ARoAHAAeAGAAZIeiAHwRJIBBTgtMS4ymAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwi7vqjhj7_rAhVGPq0KHQ5uAqQ4ChDh1QMIDQ)

Comment: [FLIP-FLOPS HAVE SLIP-SLAPPED FROM POOLSIDE TO HIGH FASHION.](https://www.orlandosentinel.com/news/os-xpm-2003-08-21-0308200438-story.html)

Comment: I think the original 'crunch-crunched" is fine. If anything, what bothers me about the sentence is it kind of seems like the wheels are going up the driveway by themselves.

Answer (score 2):

I think that 'the Model T's wheels crunched' would be the most natural sounding. While 'crunch-crunched' is not incorrect, it would give me pause as a reader since it is not a common phrase.

Comment: Sarah, welcome to EL&U.  Please take a moment to [tour] the site and read the [FAQ] to familiarize yourself with the format.  Can you add any style guide references or resources that support your intuitions here?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I agree that

> the wheels crunched up the drive

Would be simple and is quite evocative, if you really wanted to use a doubling I'd try

> The wheels sounded "crunch crunch" as they drove up the drive.

Or

> With a crunch, crunch, the Model-T drove up the drive.

You can probably get away with the "crunch-crunched" but to me it sounds quite awkward.